# Cannot install pyephem for python3

Tags: python

I cannot install the pyephem module to my Pi. 
When I do `sudo pip3 install pyephem`

I get the following error message:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pyephem
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyephem/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyephem (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyephem
```

So I guess the real question is how to get the SSL module on the Pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you have the wrong package name, it should be ephem not pyephem. You need to make sure the python3-dev package is installed first. You can do this with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Then install pyephem for Python 3 with the following command:

```
pip3 install ephem
```

If you also want to install the version for Python 2.x the required commands are:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
pip3 install ephem
```

Alternatively you can download and install from a source file:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/c3/2c/9e1a815add6c222a0d4bf7c644e095471a934a39bc90c201f9550a8f7f14/ephem-3.7.6.0.tar.gz#md5=405a109f3017251ecd8c2890d850f649
```

Unpack the archive:

```
tar -zxvf ephem-3.7.6.0.tar.gz
```

enter the ephem-3.7.6.0 directory:

```
cd ephem-3.7.6.0
```

and run:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

**Note:** You may need to run the last command as root.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error message. Funny though, since the Python 2 method works

Comment: It works here are you sure you used the python 3 version of the 2 commands?

Comment: Try this first  sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev  Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: I'm not using a virtual environment. Should I?

Comment: Can I manually install if I downloaded the package via browser from the website?

Comment: Updated answer with source install instructions

Comment: Just to let Steve know that I used his excellent method of downloading and installing from a source file the PyEphem package, using wget as above, and it installed with no problems. I had been getting install failures using "pip-3.2 install ephem" with the package not being found, also something about SSL when I used PIP only (as reported in several other posts). Even though I followed several 'solutions', including installing Python3-dev, nothing worked, except this method.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add new life to a old post and for a change,  offer a suggestion I found.

I was setting up a RPi with WeeWx,  a python based weather reporting program, that called for adding PyEphem, (the web site spelling of the name ).  I tried the above on a RPi model 2, with a new install Legacy Buster, with no results.  I found this site, which explains PyEphem purpose in detail,  and offers a simple way to install.

sudo pip install ephem

The web site says you need a C compiler and the pip Python installer tool.

https://pypi.org/project/ephem/

The C compiler was built in and I added pip by using:

sudo apt install python3-pip,

followed by:

sudo pip3 install ephem

Good luck.